# Loop based on repeated text in document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word document made up of many Chapters. The document is not styled, everything is text, but each Chapter starts on its own line with "Chapter #" (no quotes). I recorded and tweaked a macro that finds the next Chapter #, blocks, copies, cuts the previous chapter, opens a new document, pastes, saves and closes. I have to click the macro for each chapter. How do I make it so I click only once and the macro repeats for the next chapters and stops when none are left?  Here is what I have:

```
Sub Breakout2()  
'  
' Breakout2 Macro  
'  
'  
   Selection.Find.ClearFormatting  
    With Selection.Find  
        .Text = "^pChapter "  
        .Replacement.Text = ""  
        .Forward = True  
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue  
        .Format = False  
        .MatchCase = True  
        .MatchWholeWord = False  
        .MatchWildcards = False  
        .MatchSoundsLike = False  
        .MatchAllWordForms = False  
    End With  
    Selection.Find.Execute  
    Selection.Find.Execute  
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdExtend  
    Selection.Cut  
    Documents.Add DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument  
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdUseDestinationStylesRecovery)  
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory "U:\Breakout\"  
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2  
    ActiveDocument.Close  
End Sub
```

Comment: Format your code correctly please

Comment: Done. (First time caller, long time listener).

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing my code:

```
Sub Breakout2()  
'  
' Breakout2 Macro  
'  
'  
Dim i
For i = 1 To 1000

{then same code as in OP}

Next i
End Sub
```